# nginx stream mode reconnect to upstream without close downstream connection

Tags: nginx, tcp, proxy, stream, restart

Hi，I am using nginx stream mode to proxy tcp connection. Could this be possible if I restart my app on the upstream, nginx could auto reconnect to upstream without lost the tcp connection on the downstream?

Answer (score 0):

I found some clue from this [HiveMQ blog post comment](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/building-a-high-availability-mqtt-cluster), hope this help. I copied them as below:

> Hi Sourav,
>
> the load balancer doesn’t have any knowledge of MQTT; at least I don’t
>   know any MQTT-aware load balancer.
>
> HiveMQ replicates its state automatically in the cluster. If a cluster
>   node goes down and the client reconnects (and is assigned to another
>   broker instance by the LB), it can resume its complete session. The
>   client does not need to resubscribe.
>
> Hope this helps, Dominik from the HiveMQ Team